# Enable autocomplete in an sqlite3 interactive shell

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite3 on a machine where I can use tab completion (ie `.read abc<tab>` will autocomplete to `.read abcdefghij.db`. I would like to know how to enable this on my personal machine.

**Edit**

Both machines are ubuntu linux and the shell is bash. I am referring to autocompletion in the sqlite interactive prompt.

Comment: I think, this question would be a better fit for http://superuser.com/

Comment: Updated to answer questions. And I am curious why this doesn't qualify as database administration. (I can take the question elsewhere if this isn't the appropriate place for it, but I'd like why it isn't appropriate.)

Comment: I think this is more of an OS than DB thing, but never mind.  If you get an answer here, then it's quite OK, I just thought that SU would be a place for getting an answer faster :)  (See also the [FAQ](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq), if you haven't already seen it.)

Comment: I see, I figured that since it was referring to the databases prompt this would be the better option. Here is the su http://superuser.com/questions/499634/enable-autocomplete-in-an-sqlite3-interactive-shell post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question was ultimately answered on [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/622282/155274).

The solution is to compile sqlite3 with readline support.